# How to use multiple core in evaluation?

Tags: parallelization, kernel

Sorry if the question is very basic, that's because I am newbie in the Mathematica.

Assume I have a module that is supposed to do a very very long calculation

> result = Table[0, {i, 100000000}]; f[x0_] :=  Module[{x = x0},
>
> For[i =0, i < 100000000, i++,
>       result[[i]] = i^2;
>       ];   ]

Now I want to take the advantage of my multicore CPU. I there any way to break the work into pieces and assign every piece to a core to do that in parallel?

Possibly it is not a simple **ParallelEvaluate**  command. Let me be more specific:

Assume this module is taking a very long **For** loop like For[i=0,i<100000000,....   . My question is if I have 8 cores on my CPU, can I break the 100 million loop job into 8x12.5 million cycles and assign each one of these 12.5 million cycles to one core?

Comment: You are not supplying enough information to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: Perhaps `ParallelDo` or `ParallelTable`, or other parallel commands.  But **not** `ParallelEvaluate`.  Which is more appropriate is hard to say without a clearer formulation of your question.  Right now details are missing that leave the question a little vague.

Comment: @IgorRivin The main module is huge and I thought it is not appropriate to enter that. It consists of 8 For loops that do around 100 million integrations. It takes 2 days to do each evaluation and I want to reduce this time.

Comment: The question is what the dependencies between these evaluations are...

Comment: @IgorRivin Actually they are not related. each cycle calculates an integral and stores the result in a matrix for further use.

Comment: If you're constructing a matrix, then `ParallelTable`, or possibly `ParallelMap`, may be appropriate.

Comment: ParallelTable[] should work,if  all you have is 100M numbers.Otherwise, you might blow out of memory.

Comment: Offtopic, but first of all try to improve computation speed without parallel computing. Start with avoiding the `For` loop

Comment: @molekyla777 That's a good hint. I have seen For loop in the Mathematica is way slower than For loop in programming languages like Objective-C or C++. Is there any fast substitute for such loops?

Comment: @Aug of course better to use funtional analog but it is not trivial task. `Do` loop faster than `For`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computation in each cycle takes little time there is no reason for paralleling this cycle. Prove:

```
ParallelTable[i, {i, 1, 1000000}]; // AbsoluteTiming (*8 cores*)
(*{0.449026, Null}*)
Table[i, {i, 1, 1000000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.011001, Null}*)
```

This is that becouse tranfering data to parallel kernels take more time than computation on it.

Post your real code please

**EDIT**

Replace construction like

```
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
some code
]
```

with constructions like

```
ParallelDo[
some code
,{i,1,n},DistributedContexts->All]
```

`DistributedContexts->All` is not recomended becouse it is distribe **all** contexts to all parallel kernels.

Comment: Thanks but the real code is so huge ( 8xFor loops, each cycles does an Integration . Total: 100 million).  Each cycle takes almost long time. The whole process takes 2 days